# SOAP Request No Response

Tags: php, xml, soap

Can you help me out or point me in the right direction, I'm trying to perform a soap request to a WSDL feed but I'm not getting anything back.

When I use standard XML everything seems to work OK - how would I write the following into an array:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?> 
<soap:Envelope xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema">
<soap:Body> 
<SupplierDirectorySearch xmlns="SOAPREQUEST"> 
<SupplierSearchDetails ClassVersion="1.0"> 
<Identification> 
<SchemeOperatorRef>59582</SchemeOperatorRef> 
<SecurityToken>MYTOKEN</SecurityToken>
</Identification>
  <ApprovedServices ServiceRepair="Y" MOT="" Tyres="" CollectionDelivery="" CourtesyCar="" WhileUWait="" Callout24Hour="" BreakdownCover="" CollectionDeliveryNotes="" CourtesyCarNotes="" Inspections=""/>
  <SupplierLocation>BB1</SupplierLocation> 
  <SearchRadiusMiles>300</SearchRadiusMiles> 
  <Preference>P</Preference> 
  <MaxReturnNumber>5</MaxReturnNumber> 
  <PageNo>0</PageNo> 
 </SupplierSearchDetails> 
 </SupplierDirectorySearch> 
</soap:Body> 
</soap:Envelope>';
```

I've written the following soap request:

```
$client = new SoapClient("URL?WSDL", $option);
$res = $client->SupplierDirectorySearch(
array('SupplierSearchDetails'=> 
  array('Identification' => array('SchemeOperatorRef'=>'61', 'SecurityToken'=>'MYTOKEN'),
    'ApprovedServices' => array(
    'ServiceRepair'=>'Y',
    'MOT'=>'',
    'Tyres'=>'',
    'CollectionDelivery'=>'',
    'CourtesyCar'=>'',
    'WhileUWait'=>'',
    'Callout24Hour'=>'',
    'BreakdownCover'=>'',
    'CollectionDeliveryNotes'=>'',
    'CourtesyCarNotes'=>'',
    'Inspections'=>'',
      ),  
    'SupplierLocation' => 'BB1',
    'SearchRadiusMiles' => '2',
    'Preference' => 'P',
    'MaxReturnNumber' => '5',
    'PageNo' => '0'
  )
  )
);
```

Nothing is coming back, I've enabled the trace and this is what's getting passed in the request:

```
REQUEST:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/"    xmlns:ns1="OneLink_ServiceBookingComponent">
<SOAP-ENV:Body><ns1:SupplierDirectorySearch>            
<ns1:SupplierSearchDetails>
<ns1:Identification>
 <ns1:SchemeOperatorRef>61</ns1:SchemeOperatorRef>
 <ns1:SecurityToken>MYTOKEN</ns1:SecurityToken>
</ns1:Identification>  

<ns1:SupplierLocation>BB1</ns1:SupplierLocation>
<ns1:SearchRadiusMiles>2</ns1:SearchRadiusMiles>
<ns1:Preference>P</ns1:Preference> 
<ns1:ApprovedServices ServiceRepair="Y" MOT="" Tyres="" CollectionDelivery=""  CourtesyCar="" WhileUWait="" Callout24Hour="" BreakdownCover="" CollectionDeliveryNotes="" CourtesyCarNotes="" Inspections=""/>
<ns1:MaxReturnNumber>5</ns1:MaxReturnNumber>
<ns1:PageNo>0</ns1:PageNo>
</ns1:SupplierSearchDetails>
</ns1:SupplierDirectorySearch>
</SOAP-ENV:Body>
</SOAP-ENV:Envelope>
```

Can anyone shed any light on this, it's racking my brain!!

---

I've just been looking, do you think I will have to code the  section like this:

```
<?php 
  $amount['_'] = 25; 
  $amount['currencyId'] = 'GBP'; 
  $encodded = new SoapVar($amount, SOAP_ENC_OBJECT); 

?>
```

Scott

Comment: Have you told PHP to display/log errors? Is any SOAP exception thrown? Note as well that there are some differences between your "working example request" and the generated request (store them in two text files and use a diff tool)

Comment: Thanks for the reply - I'm just getting a response, that says the following:

[SupplierCount] => 0

There should be 6...

Comment: Ok, then you certainly have to debug your SOAP service now :)

Comment: How do i do that Frosty??

Comment: Maybe create a log file from your service code, and output some debug traces into that file, to understand why 0 is returned instead of 6.

Comment: The problem is I don't have any control over the actual soap service... Can you help me out anymore?

Comment: If your initial example works, check differences with your generated query. If it seems Ok, I'm afraid you will have to file a bug to the SOAP service maintainer :)

Comment: The funny thing is if you request a curl to the URL using the above original XML file it works... any other idea?

Comment: If soap envelope is working then what about differences in HTTP headers being sent by PHP-SOAP and cURL requests?

Comment: I think i need to add attributes to the soap xml??